# What is the best practise for using @output decorator twice?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have done some logic using @Output event emitter for each variable to emit.

```
    @Output() public test1 = new EventEmitter<void>();
@Output() public test2 = new EventEmitter<void>()
```

But now the question is why I need to repeat the @output() decorator twice since both has void. Is this only way to use this or is this possible to improve the code as much better?

Comment: This is a valid way to declare event emitters. The angular documentation shows this as well:  https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Comment: The "output" is used in your parent as `<app-child (test1)="something($event)">`. when you change a variable in child component, you can say to the parent that the variable has changed and pass it

Answer (score 1):

Just assign it to 1 variable and pass several values to it

Try the below and see if it works:

```
@Output() public test = new EventEmitter<any>();

this.test.emit({test1, test2, ...});
```